# Receive array inputs from a single line in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Inputs are in the format: {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
How should i split it into multiple elements using c#

Comment: By your own hands, no? Have you even tried anything?

Comment: have you tried `yourArray = input.Split(',');`

Comment: I think we need a close reason "Basic stuff".

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Try this : string input = "{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}";
            int[] output = input.Split(new char[] { '{', ',', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

Answer (score 2):

First remove the brackets and spaces,

```
input = input.Replace("{", "");
input = input.Replace("}", "");
input = input.Replace(" ", "");
```

Leaving you with this:

```
10,20,30,40,50
```

Now you can split the string at the commas using this function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Which would look like this:

```
IList<string> result = input.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```